# First OOP in Python 3: Pygame Pong

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, pygame, pong

I have been studying Python for a few months and just recently decided to stop avoiding OOP and reworked a Pong game to a more object oriented style. Please tell me how I should improve my code.

Some of the code is an adaptation from this [Stack Overflow question about menu state](//stackoverflow.com/q/14700889/).

There is a known problem with the `MenuScene.handle_events()` function, such that I need to press the space or return key multiple times to it catch the event, but I don't consider it to be a significant bug.

### main.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import pygame   
from core.config import Colors, Globals
from core.scene import GameScene, SceneManager

def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((Globals.win_width,Globals.win_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    manager = SceneManager()
    running= True
    pygame.init()
    while running:
        clock.tick(120)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
        screen.fill(Colors.black)
        manager.scene.render(screen)
        manager.scene.handle_events(pygame.event.get())
        manager.scene.update()
        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### scene.py

```
from .actors import Player,Enemy,Ball
from .config import Colors, Globals
import pygame

class SceneManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.go_to(MenuScene())

    def go_to(self, scene):
        self.scene = scene
        self.scene.manager = self

class Scene(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def render(self, screen):
        raise NotImplementedError
    def update(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
    def handle_events(self, events):
        raise NotImplementedError

class MenuScene(Scene):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MenuScene,self).__init__()
        pygame.font.init()
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 56)
        self.sfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 32)
        pass
    def render(self, screen):      
        screen.fill(Colors.green)
        text1 = self.font.render('Pong Rework', True, (255, 255, 255))
        text2 = self.sfont.render('> press SPACE to start <', True, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(text1, (200, 50))
        screen.blit(text2, (200, 350))
    def update(self):
        pass
    def handle_events(self,events):
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and (e.key == pygame.K_SPACE or e.key == pygame.K_RETURN):
                self.manager.go_to(GameScene()) 

class GameScene(Scene):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GameScene, self).__init__()
        pygame.font.init()
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("Comic Sans MS", 30)
        self.player = Player()
        self.enemy = Enemy()
        self.points ={"player": 0, "enemy": 0}
        self.player_score=self.font.render("{}".format(self.points["player"]),1,Colors.white)
        self.enemy_score=self.font.render("{}".format(self.points["enemy"]),1, Colors.white)       
        self.ball = Ball()

    def render(self,screen):
        screen.blit(self.player_score,(150,100))
        screen.blit(self.enemy_score,(630,100))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,Colors.white,self.player)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,Colors.white,self.enemy)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,Colors.white,self.ball)

    def update(self):
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        up,down = [pressed[key] for key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_DOWN)]
        self.handle_point()
        self.player.update(up,down)
        self.enemy.update(self.ball.y)
        self.ball.update(self.player,self.enemy)
        return

    def handle_events(self, events):
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pass

    def handle_point(self):

        def update_points(key) :
            self.points[key] +=1
            self.player_score=self.font.render("{}".format(self.points["player"]),1,Colors.white)
            self.enemy_score=self.font.render("{}".format(self.points["enemy"]),1, Colors.white)

        if self.ball.x <= self.ball.width:
            update_points("enemy")
            self.ball.reset()                     
        if self.ball.x >= (Globals.win_width + self.ball.width):
            update_points("player")
            self.ball.reset()
            self.ball.dir_x *= -1
```

### actors.py

```
import pygame
from .config import Globals, Colors
from math import cos,sin,radians,pi
class Player(pygame.Rect):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player,self).__init__(20,225,20,150)
        self.velocity = 5
        print("player class initated")
    def update(self,up,down):
        if up and self.y >= 10:
            self.y -= self.velocity
        if down and self.y <= Globals.win_height - (self.height +10):
            self.y += self.velocity
        pass

class Enemy(pygame.Rect):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Enemy,self).__init__(760,225,20,150)
        self.velocity = 3
        print("enemy class initated")
    def update(self,ballYpos):
        middle = self.y + self.height /2
        if ballYpos != middle:
            if ballYpos > middle and self.y <= Globals.win_height- (self.height+self.velocity):
                self.y += self.velocity
            if ballYpos < middle and self.y >= self.velocity*2:
                self.y -= self.velocity


class Ball(pygame.Rect):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ball,self).__init__(400,300,20,20)
        self.velocity = 5
        self.angle = radians(0)
        self.dir_x = cos(self.angle)
        self.dir_y = -sin(self.angle)
        print("Ball class instancieted")
    def reset(self):
        self.x =400
        self.y = 300
        self.angle = radians(0)
        self.dir_x = cos(self.angle)
        self.dir_y = -sin(self.angle)
    def update(self,player,enemy):       
        self.x += self.dir_x * self.velocity
        self.y += self.dir_y * self.velocity

        self.handle_bound_collision()
        self.handle_paddle_collision(player,enemy)

    def handle_bound_collision(self):
        if self.y <=  0 or self.y>= Globals.win_height - 10:
            self.dir_y*= -1.05

    def handle_paddle_collision(self,player,enemy):
        intersectY = self.y
        if self.colliderect(player):
            relativeIntersectY = (player.y + (player.height / 2) ) - intersectY
            normalizedRelativeIntersectY = relativeIntersectY / (player.height/2)
            self.angle = radians(normalizedRelativeIntersectY * 60)
            self.dir_x = cos(self.angle)
            self.dir_y = -sin(self.angle)

        if self.colliderect(enemy):
            relativeIntersectY = (enemy.y + (enemy.height/2)) - intersectY
            normalizedRelativeIntersectY = relativeIntersectY / (enemy.height/2) 
            self.angle = radians(normalizedRelativeIntersectY * 60)
            self.dir_x = -cos(self.angle)
            self.dir_y = sin(self.angle)
```

### config.py

```
class Globals:
    win_width = 800
    win_height = 600

class Colors:
    white = (255,255,255)
    black = (0,0,0)
    red = (255,0,0)
    green = (0,255,0)
    blue = (0,0,255)
```

Comment: If there is a significant known bug, then you should fix it before asking for a review.

Comment: Sorry, the bug was not significant in my point of view as this is only a study case of oop, i shouldnt have mentioned it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Gameplay:**

By placing the paddle in a specific position I managed to break the game (see the image). I think you should add a random starting angle when the game restarts.

Also, as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pong#Gameplay) says the game should be finished once someone reaches eleven points.

[image: I_broke_the_game.jpg]

**Code:**

You violate some of the [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style recommendations, namely:

- [order of imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)
- [blank lines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines)
- [maximum line length](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)
- [variable names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) (e.g. `normalizedRelativeIntersectY` should be `normalized_relative_intersect_y`)

---

In some methods like `GameScene.update` or `Player.update` you have empty `return` or `pass` statements after code blocks. They are redundant and should be removed.

---

Consider changing the class `Globals` that consists of only width and height of the screen to a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
import namedtuple

Size = namedtuple('Size', ['width', 'height'])
WINDOW_SIZE = Size(width=800, height=600)
```

So, you could use it in two different ways. As a tuple in `main`:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE)
```

and as a class with `width` and `height` attributes, for example in `Player.update`:

```
if down and self.y <= WINDOW_SIZE.height - (self.height + 10):
```

---

In the *config.py* you have a class with colors, but pygame has a special class for that already: [`pygame.Color`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html).
For example, in `main` you would simply write:

```
screen.fill(pygame.Color('black'))
```

I think it would make sense to move lots of hardcoded values as fonts and dimensions of objects to the *config.py* file though. Also, be careful, some of your hardcoded values depend on each other, as in the `Player` class where you check if the paddle is going over the border. That `10` in `if up and self.y >= 10:` should be tied with the paddle's dimensions `super(Player,self).__init__(20,225,20,150)`.

By the way, the last piece should be rewritten as `super().__init__(20, 225, 20, 150)`. It's been like this since Python 3.0: [PEP 3135 -- New Super](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/).

---

In some places you convert integers to strings using `format`:

```
self.player_score=self.font.render("{}".format(self.points["player"]),1,Colors.white)
```

but it can be done by using `str` function:

```
self.player_score = self.font.render(str(self.points["player"]), 1, pygame.Color('white'))
```

---

Finally, don't print things like `print("player class initated")`. As these things are for debugging purposes, consider using [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module.

---

On overall, well done! I'm not a fan of OOP but it was easy to read and understand your code.